# itunesconnect detects ads from my app even if I haven't used one

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, identifier

I submitted a new version update to itunesconnect (meaning I have been approved and I have not changed much but some bug fixes).

I submitted an app today. Where it asks if the app uses ads, I checked no, since the app does not use it and having trouble with it I removed the AdFramework.

Upon clicking submit, it failed. An error was detected, saying that they have detected advertising identifier in my app. I checked my app again, looking for adFramework, it is not there. I was forced to check "yes" if my app uses ads just to continue.

I remembered though that I updated all my SDKs to latest versions. I use inMobi, Facebook, Google Plus and Google Analytics. Do any of these SDKs cause the problem? I have read some issues with the latest Facebook SDK.

Comment: It's very likely one of the libraries (Facebook, I'm looking at you...) uses the advertising identifier. Checking "yes" for ads is probably the right way to proceed.

Comment: Checking yes when your app doesn't serve ads is a guaranteed rejection

Comment: I thought so. But how will I fix this?

Comment: @Paulw11 **a)** that's absolutely untrue **b)** the question asks you if the app uses *the advertising identifier* which the FB SDK [definitely does](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#IDFA).